# How to set a default timezone for all?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used  php/mysql  Now() function that stores user's device current time.

But I want to set a default timezone for all users at   ('America/Los_Angeles').

```html
$insert =" insert into comments (comment,date) values('$comment',NOW()) ";
```

**EDIT**

i did this and worked

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$insert =" insert into comments (comment,date) values('$comment','$date') ";
```

Comment: You're confusing PHP with mysql, `NOW()` is a mysql function, not a PHP function. You'll need to set the timezone for your mysql server to the same as your PHP setting.

Comment: with constant value set time zone and use everywhere

Comment: $constant = 'America/Los_Angeles';                                                        $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($constant));   // set constant

Comment: Don't do this. Store UTC dates in MySQL and convert them to the correct timezone on retrieval. MySQL already does this with timestamps so this way you're being consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Set mysql timezone same as php.
Check it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

$constant = 'America/Los_Angeles'; $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($constant)); // set constan